# Error when compiling plugin filter on ImageJ

Tags: java, image-processing, imagej

Getting this error message whenever I am trying to compile a plugin filter. Not sure what is causing that.

```
ImageJ 1.53a; Java 1.8.0_172 [64-bit]; Mac OS X 10.15.7; 33MB of 3000MB (1%)

warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
/private/var/folders/nm/nftqfvnn4_7c87p06n3qztl00000gn/T/AppTranslocation/071310B3-FF74-405F-B175-3C92927EC9DB/d/ImageJ.app/plugins/Filters/Filter_Plugin.java:9: error: error while writing Filter_Plugin: /private/var/folders/nm/nftqfvnn4_7c87p06n3qztl00000gn/T/AppTranslocation/071310B3-FF74-405F-B175-3C92927EC9DB/d/ImageJ.app/plugins/Filters/Filter_Plugin.class (Read-only file system)
public class Filter_Plugin implements PlugInFilter {
       ^
1 error
1 warning
```

Comment: At the end of the line, there's a message "`(Read-only file system)`". Looks like the user running `javac` does not have write permission to the target folder.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely caused by the ***Path Randomization*** feature in Mac OSX (maybe because you're running ImageJ from within a mounted dmg file?).

See also this topic on the Image.sc forum:

https://forum.image.sc/t/imagej-stopped-working-when-we-upgraded-to-macos-sierra-10-12/3005/7?u=imagejan

Quoting from there:

> You can disable path randomization by moving ImageJ.app out of the ImageJ folder and then copying it back.

In general, issues with ImageJ (both usage and development) are best discussed on https://forum.image.sc/tag/imagej.